# Parallel transaction issue using custom UOW with ORM(EF6)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, orm, repository-pattern

A little background I'm trying to implement Generic Repository and UOW pattern along with Entity Framework as ORM.I have written custom UnitOFWork class with methods

1.BeginTransaction.
2.CommmitTransaction
3.RollBackTransaction
4.SaveChanges
5.IsInTransaction
6.Dispose.

```
public class UnitOfWork: IUnitOfWork
{
  private DbTransaction transaction;
  private readonly DbContext context;
  public UnitOfWork(DBContext dbContext )
  {
    context = dbContext ;
  }   
  public void Begintransaction()
  {
    transaction = context.Database.Connection.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel);
  }
  public void CommitTransaction()
  {
    context.SaveChanges();
    transaction.Commit();
    ReleaseCurrentTransaction();
  }
   ....
   ....
}
```

My Generic repository class

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
  private dbContext;
  protected DBContext Context
  {
     get
     {
       return dbContext != null? dbContext : dbContext = GetContextFromFactory();
     }
  }
  public void Add<T>(T entity)
  {
    dbContext.Set<T>.Add(entity);
  }
}
```

My PersonRepository.

```
public class PersonRepository : Repository
{
  public void AddPerson(Person person)
  {
     using(var uow = new UnitOfWork(Context)
     {
       try
       {
         uow.BeginTransaction();
         Add(person);
         uow.CommitTransaction();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
         uow.RollBackTransaction();
     log.Error("This Exception:",ex);
       }
     }
  }
} 

var repo = new PersonRepository();
Person person = GetPerson();
repo.AddPerson(person);
```

When I run this code to save person object it throws exception on context.SaveChanges() in CommitTransaction() method of UOW.
Exception is "SqlConnection does not support parallel transactions."

1. Am I doing something wrong in the code?
2. Transactions in UOW has some issues?
3. UOW transactions in conjunction with ORM are not supported?
4. If transactions are not supported then what is the purpose of UnityOfWork pattern when DbContext or any other ORM implements unitofwork pattern by default?

I would appreciate your suggestions and comments.

**[Update]**
I have fixed this issue by making context to accept current transaction which is already existing. My fix was in the code CommitTransaction().I need your comments.

From this.

```
  public void CommitTransaction()
  {
   context.SaveChanges();
    transaction.Commit();
    ReleaseCurrentTransaction();
  }
```

To This.

```
 public void CommitTransaction()
  {
    context.UseTransaction(this.transaction);
    context.SaveChanges();
    transaction.Commit();
    ReleaseCurrentTransaction();
  }
```

Are there any downside for this approach? Please share your comments.

Answer (score 1):

1. DbContext is NOT threadsafe - do not use dbcontext across threads.
2. Connection strings should make sure connections allow MARS. See Below.
3. UoW patterns are best practice with ORMs.  Supported by EF.
4. EF framework manage the transaction for you. No need to add Transaction handling to your basic repository class.
   add object 1,   change object2,    remove object 3,
   Then   SaveChanges.
   Will be performed as a transaction by EF. Without dirty uncommitted  reads.
   If one of the updates fails, the changes are rolled back.
5. Transactions via message queues.
   [EF and transaction scope for use with message queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738523%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
   General info on when you might want to use transactions in EF
    [Considerations for using transactions and how to in EF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896325%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
6. Dispose of your Context instance ASAP. Renew regularly is general recommendation

connection String: see MultipleActiveResultSets=true

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConn" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDbName ;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: My DbContext scope is per HttpRequest for web app and for windows it is shared static context.Is that going to work?                                    Please see my update and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I expect the httpreq will work. But do not understand why you want to control the scope manually. It looks like single db repository UoW update. Why not let EF do it. Be careful with long running static contexts in windows apps. You cant use multi threading, and can lead to  bloated contexts over time. even in windows apps, renew the context is recommended. it cheap to do.

Comment: I didn't get your point **But do not understand why you want to control the scope manually.** I thought that's how it should be, I'm not aware of in built options. May be because I tried to follow persistence ignorance pattern. please enlighten me. By the way I have a webservice and windows service that uses repository.For now I have single repository. Thanks for your time.

Comment: try a simple test. create new context.   add 2 records.  make sure one will result in dup key or some error. SaveChanges.  EF will ROLLBACK the other record.  ef uses transactions. does it all for you.